# How to access the example values for a behat scenario outline?

Tags: php, bdd, behat

This should really be something simple and straight forward but I haven't been able to find an answer anywhere online. When using a scenario outline in Behat, how can I access the example values inside my test?  For the below example, how would i access the email address in my test?  My automated test will basically fill in a text field with an email address so I want to know how can i fill it with the email_value being used for this particular scenario that is being run?

```
Feature: Email validation
Background: Given I am on “www.somewebsite.com”
Scenario Outline: Confirm email validation

Given I fill in the email field with “”
When I submit the form
Then I should see “”

**Examples:**
|      |  |
|                   | A validation message that email is required|
| steve@            | A validation message that email must be valid |
| valid@email.com   | The review page |
```

This is a function my test case is calling, it's just finding the textfield and filling in an email address... Instead of filling it with "testing", I want to actually fill it out with the email_value from my outline.  How can I access that value from within my function below?

```
public function fillForm()
    {
         $element = $this->driver->findElement($this->emailTextField);
         $element->click();
         $element->sendKeys("testing");

         #Please review your response and confirm.
    }
```

2) 2nd question somewhat related is that I want to check the submission_result to see if it doesn't contain the word "validation message" then I know it was a successfully (e.g. valid) email and will take me to a success page rather than display an error.

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

These are some out of the box defined steps, you need to check if you have everything you need and if not you need to define them yourself.

As for different types of parameters

Example:
  `I fill in "field" for "value"`

the field and field are passed as parameters to the associated method, so you need to have access to that method if you want to print them or log them somewhere.

For scenario outline:

```
  Scenario Outline:
    Given I fill in "" with "value_placeholder"

    Examples:
      | field_placeholder | value_placeholder |
      | field_identifier  | actual_value      |
```

Use an editor that supports Behat and ctrl/command + click on the steps and see how to use them.

Comment: I'm just using a text editor (notepad++) now as I have a quick project to work on.  When you say it's passed as a parameter, how?  This is the function for the Given, how do i access that parameter? I tried to make the function take in $email_value but it didn't work, i have no idea what the parameter should be called.   

Please advise =)                                                                                                              /**
     * @Given I fill in the email field with “<email_value>”
     */
    public function iFillInTheEmailFieldWithEmailValue()
    {
    }